# why am I getting same quote from jsonp result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following jquery code, that pulls json data from a url; however, it is giving me the same quote over and over, instead of random. If I use url directly on browser it does randomize the quote. What am I missing? Thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
  $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  console.log(a[0].content + " " + a[0].title)
  $("#quote-content").html(a[0].content)
  $("#quote-title").html(a[0].title)
});
  });
```

Comment: I'm guessing perhaps a caching issue. adding a timestamp to the end of you request might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either turn off AJAX cache for jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  //...
});
```

Or you could change the url for every request (so it doesn't get cached), something like this could work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=&"+new Date().getTime(), function(a) {
      //...
    });
  });
});
```

Also, I don't think you need the `callback=` parameter